# Continuous integration for angular 2 cli project with jenkins

Tags: angular, jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm new to angular 2 and jenkins both.I have created one small web app with angular 2.
Also, i'm maintaining the code through gitlab repository.
I want to setup Continuous integration with jenkis for angular 2 app.

Basically what i want is when i push the code in any branch then jenkins will detect it and start the running unit test which are written in angular 2 app.If test case fails it should send the mail.

So how can i do that? What are the steps do required to setup whole Continuous integration?

Comment: I have setup angular 2 cli project and jenkins. In jenkins  have just setup git plugin inwhich whenever you push code your repository jenkins will detect it and run the build.That's it.

Comment: cool, sounds like you're well on your way! keep going!

Comment: I have a question, what configuration i have to made in jenkins for ci enviornment? Currently it is just buliding the job but i wnat to tun unit test in each build then how can i do that?

Comment: before it was in jenkins, how were you running the tests? you probably want a similar command and then to output junit-style xml so jenkins can parse the results.

Comment: i'm using 'ng test' command to run angular 2 cli project test cases.